# I want to select the username textfield from listview and use that username to delete data present in mysql database

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, listview

I want to show MySQL table data in listview and also have to put delete button on the bottom of screen. User have to select list item and by clicking on delete button the particular data should be removed from mysql table and listview. I can display records properly but cannot select the username field from list item.

**View User Activity**

```
public class ViewUser extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String VIEW_URL= "http://ajaygohel012.000webhostapp.com/ViewUser.php";

    ListView listUser;
    List<User> userlist;
    private Button btnDelete;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_user);

        listUser= findViewById(R.id.listUser);
        userlist= new ArrayList<>();
        btnDelete= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

        final TextView viewUserName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewUserName);

        loadUserList();

        listUser.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                listUser.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });

        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final String username = viewUserName.getText().toString();
                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                            try {
                                JSONObject js = new JSONObject(response);
                                boolean success = js.getBoolean("success");
                                if (success){
                                    finish();
                                    startActivity(getIntent());
                                }
                            }catch(JSONException e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    }
                };

                DeleteRequest deleteRequest= new DeleteRequest(username, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(ViewUser.this);
                queue.add(deleteRequest);
            }
        });
    }
    private void loadUserList(){
        final ProgressBar progressBar= (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        StringRequest stringRequest= new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, VIEW_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

                    for (int i=0;jsonArray.length()>i;i++){
                        final JSONObject j= jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        User user=new User();

                        String name = j.getString("name");
                        String empcode = j.getString("empcode");
                        String location = j.getString("location");
                        String department = j.getString("department");
                        String username = j.getString("username");

                        user.setName(name);
                        user.setEmpcode(empcode);
                        user.setLocation(location);
                        user.setDepartment(department);
                        user.setUsername(username);
                        userlist.add(user);
                    }
                    ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(userlist, ViewUser.this);
                    listUser.setAdapter(adapter);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(ViewUser.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view==btnDelete){
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, ViewUser.class));
        }
    }
}
```

**DeleteRequest**

```
class DeleteRequest extends StringRequest{
    private static final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL= "http://ajaygohel012.000webhostapp.com/DeleteUser.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public DeleteRequest(String username, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        super(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("username", username);
    }
    public Map<String, String> getParams(){
        return params;
    }

}
```

**User class**

```
public class User {
    String name, empcode, location, department, username;

    public User(){
        this.name=name;
        this.empcode=empcode;
        this.location=location;
        this.department=department;
        this.username=username;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getEmpcode() {
        return empcode;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setEmpcode(String empcode) {
        this.empcode = empcode;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

**ListViewAdapter**

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
    private List<User> userlist;
    private Context cntx;

    public ListViewAdapter(List<User> userlist, Context cntx){
        super(cntx, R.layout.list_item, userlist);
        this.userlist=userlist;
        this.cntx=cntx;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater= LayoutInflater.from(cntx);
        View listViewitem= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,null, true);

        TextView viewName= listViewitem.findViewById(R.id.viewName);
        TextView viewEmployeeCode= listViewitem.findViewById(R.id.viewEmployeeCode);
        TextView viewLocation= listViewitem.findViewById(R.id.viewLocation);
        TextView viewDepartment= listViewitem.findViewById(R.id.viewDepartment);
        TextView viewUserName= listViewitem.findViewById(R.id.viewUserName);

        User user=userlist.get(position);

        viewName.setText(user.getName());
        viewEmployeeCode.setText(user.getEmpcode());
        viewLocation.setText(user.getLocation());
        viewDepartment.setText(user.getDepartment());
        viewUserName.setText(user.getUsername());

        return listViewitem;
    }
}
```

**DeleteUser PHP**

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "abc", "xyz", "id3275958_user");


if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
$username = $_POST['username'];

$result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM user WHERE username = $username");

$response = array();

if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "User successfully deleted";
} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No User found";
}
} else {
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";
}
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

I also made php script and giving me proper response. Just want send username from my app is remaining.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine right...

> Just want send username from my app is remaining.

I would suggest from `btnDelete` on your Activity.

```
btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final String username = viewUserName.getText().toString();
            Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject js = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = js.getBoolean("success");
// TODO: you could add Response Here from your backend the remaining username
                            if (success){
                                finish();
                                startActivity(getIntent());
                            }
                        }catch(JSONException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

           ...
        }
    });
```

Like response of, then display or prompt user

```
username_count

String count = js.getString("username_count"); // Just convert into Int if you needed
```

Comment: my username is not get selected and passing to my php script thats the problem. @Ric17101

Comment: I've tried your API on my POSTMan, but is not working especially the [DeleteUser.php](http://ajaygohel012.000webhostapp.com/DeleteUser.php), try to test your WEB Api first or POST it here so we can help.

Comment: Check i added a php script and giving me a proper response.  {"success":0,"message":"Required field(s) is missing"}      @Ric17101

Comment: Have you tried to POST an Argument of 'username'?  you just access your page without any parameter, you should run your DeleteUser.php with correct parameter/argument first.

or you can post your PHP code for Delete Function

Comment: I updated my delete php code here u can check @Ric17101

Comment: From this line, you can check whether the connection is ok;
`$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "abc", "xyz", "id3275958_user");`

`if(!$con)
{ // creation of the connection object failed
    die("connection object not created: ".mysqli_error($con));
}

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{ // creation of the connection object has some other error
    die("Connect failed: ".mysqli_connect_errno()." : ". mysqli_connect_error());
}`

Comment: but the thing is when i click on Delete button it crashes the app and my list item is also not get selected . so something is wrong in android code. @ Ric17101

Comment: The error is happened when you decode the response from the PHP right?  Then you should first determine what is the content of that response to help you what is wrong from the BackEnd after calling the WebAPI.

Comment: WebApi working fine i guess. Directly put this link in browser- ajaygohel012.000webhostapp.com/DeleteUser.php

Answer (score 0):

After this line of your PHP, you can check whether the connection is ok;

`$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "abc", "xyz", "id3275958_user");`

```
if(!$connection)
{ // creation of the connection object failed
    die("connection object not created: ".mysqli_error($con));
}

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{ // creation of the connection object has some other error
    die("Connect failed: ".mysqli_connect_errno()." : ". mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Comment: Try to use add this on your PHP file first to see what's wrong, we cannot conclude what is happenning from the backend with that reponse of `{"success":0,"message":"Required field(s) is missing"}`, right?

Comment: Yes i added that part.. and its giving me response... I m not giving my username thats y it is giving me this response.. {"success":0,"message":"Required field(s) is missing"}.... if i will give my username than it will perform delete operation

Comment: Post the response after you call your API with existing username, we'll check

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot of reading, but I think the follow link will help

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-mysql-tutorial-to-perform-basic-crud-operation/